# How add event listener to '+' zoom element?

Tags: yandex-api, yandex-maps

I try add event listener to '+' zoom element icon when him state is disabled. please help me.

[JSFIDDLE here.](http://jsfiddle.net/1x2w8fsb/31/)

code:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap,
    collectionMarkers,
    currCoords = [55.76, 37.64];

function init(){     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: currCoords,
        zoom: 18
    });  

    const zoomControl = new window.ymaps.control.ZoomControl();
    myMap.controls.event.add('disabled', () => {
        console.log('+ is disable')
    });
};
```

Comment: The zoom element has the class `ymaps-2-1-68-zoom__icon`, so maybe you can add the listener on that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this workaround?

```
myMap.events.add('boundschange', function(event) {
  if (event.get('newZoom') !== event.get('oldZoom')) {
    myMap.layers.getZoomRange().then(function(zoomRange) {
      if (event.get('newZoom') === zoomRange[1]) {
        console.log('+ is disable')
      }
    })
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tw3qryh/